# We need another volunteer Moderator♦

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderators

We need [a 3rd moderator](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) for this site.

Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community, but until this site reaches a critical mass to hold an election, we need to appoint another provisional Moderator to fill that role.

Please nominate folks you might like to see become the provisional Moderators for this site. Your input will provide some valuable support to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)**.

### The Nomination Process:

- Nominate a user by adding an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity. I added a short template (below) to help you with that process.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this."
- Nominations can include links to other activities: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **The nominee should indicate their acceptance** by editing the answer (not commenting) to say they accept. Optionally, nominees are encouraged to write a bit about themselves following the nomination. I added a short template (below) to help you with that process.

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are seeking out members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active on the site.
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities.
- Leads by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Here is an example nomination entry. You can copy-and-paste from the format below:

> `##[username](<main profile link>)`
>
> `##[Meta Profile](<meta profile link>)`
>
> `Notes:`
>
> `<why you feel nominee would be a useful addition to the pro tem choices>`

### Accepting a nomination

Please 'edit' the nomination post to indicate whether you "accept" or "decline". Optionally, you are encouraged to write a bit about yourself following the nomination. Here is a short template you can add to the bottom of the post.

> `---`
>
> `I accept/decline this nomination`
>
> `I am <name>. <interest in this site?> <fun fact?> ← all optional. I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are`…

Comment: I don't mind a 3rd mod, but could you be a bit more detailed as to why we need a 3rd mod? I've only been active Pets SE for a couple of months, and (as much as I would want to be it the other way) the traffic of this specific community isn't that hectic, review queues are of 4 posts at most(that I've seen). And the two current mods seem to have it under control. **This is just my personal opinion**

Comment: Can we ask questions to nominees?

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton All sites start out with [at least three moderators](http://pets.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) as a baseline and one of yours resigned. The minimum number isn't about handling the load, but having that redundancy so the task doesn't fall to one person (should #2 go missing or on vacation or something)... and also having more diversity so high end decisions are coming from more than 1-2 people with more *accountability* to those who have the same abilities. Checks and balances.

Comment: I still don't see this "rule" in the link provided but I understand it, and it makes sense.

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton you can ask questions of the nominees [see the SE elections in process](http://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1), they may or may not answer.  We are a smaller community so I would expect things to be simpler here.  Also keep in mind, we are still in beta phase, so no one is actually elected, Stack Exchange staff will appoint someone, using the nominations and voting as **PART** of their decision making process.

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton Since there is no actual election, if you need a point of clarification or are simply curious about a nomination, you can post it as a comment below their post.

Comment: I wonder if we're just a touch too small, there doesn't seem to be a lot of people jumping at it. I'm a bit surprised.

Comment: Theoretically, I am interested, but I didn't know if that would be odd, considering history.

Comment: @AshleyNunn I can't think of any history that would make anything odd about you holding the position, you already have the buttons on another site which looks to be past beta, and means your are elected there.  Go ahead and post yourself.

Comment: Any updates????

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [Ashley Nunn](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/53/ashley-nunn)

### [Meta Profile](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/users/53/ashley-nunn)

Notes:

I'm nominating myself because I feel like I might make an awesome mod here. Some of you may know that I used to be a moderator here when the site was just starting, but I had to step down due to extenuating circumstances. I'd like a second shot at helping this site be awesome - I love my pets, I love that we have a place where people can get good quality information about their pet issues, and I'd love to keep helping this site be awesome. I'm already a mod on another site, so I have some idea of how things work, and I've seen this site through its beginning stages. I'd love the chance to dig back in again and continue to help this site grow and become even more of a strong part of the SE network and a place to turn to for good advice about the animals we all love so much.

Comment: Yay!  I'm very glad to see this.

Comment: I'm in favour of this!

Comment: Okay, Ashley Nunn is all set with the Moderator♦ diamond. Congratulations, Ashley!

Comment: @RobertCartaino Thanks so much! :)

Comment: @AshleyNunn - Welcome back. :)

Answer (score 4):

### [Monica Cellio](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/31/monica-cellio)

### [Meta Profile](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/users/31/monica-cellio)

Notes:

Monica is clearly an experienced and knowledgeable pet owner who has been an active participant on the site since the very beginning and has supplied good questions and answers. She's also an experienced moderator from other sites and that helps with keeping the moderation here fair and balanced. We're also not a high moderator workload, so I don't think moderating here will add a lot of additional overhead for her.

---

I decline this nomination, with thanks for the kind words.  There are stronger candidates and my *recent* activity here has been low.  I do hope to increase my participation, but that doesn't require a diamond.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - tagging you, not sure if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks John.  I'm not going to formally respond just yet (need to think about it), but I'd like to point out that I have four other diamonds and this would be a great opportunity for someone new to moderation (because you have two other experienced mods and not so much activity that mods struggle to keep up).

Answer (score 2):

### [Spiderman (Matt)](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/481/spiderman)

### [Meta Profile](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/users/481/spiderman)

Notes:

Matt aka Spiderman, has the highest rep of those who have not had a turn at being a moderator.  I have always felt he would be a good fit for the job, during our last look for a Moderator Pro Tempor, he did throw his hat in, but some how I got the job instead of him.

He consistently makes good posts, visits the site regularly and has shown himself to be level headed.  He has a zoo at home and has contributed greatly to help this site become the success that it is.

---

I'm going to have to decline. While I appreciate the nomination, I don't think I have the time to dedicate to being an effective moderator.

Comment: Now I am wondering if posting this suggestion was really counter productive.  Matt last stopped in just prior to the post, and no one has voted up or down on the nomination, nor proposed themselves or others for the position.  I was just trying to get the ball rolling.  There are a number of people who would make good candidates.

Comment: Desire to do it is a consideration too... I guess there isn't a large interest in moderating for what it's worth.

Comment: @JamesJenkins weekends tend to be slower.

Comment: Matt has a good body of participation (main and meta) and experience with a variety of pet types.  I think he'd be a good choice.

Comment: I have commitment issues so I'll need to think on this before I accept/decline. Either way I appreciate the sentiment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are other users as well that are good matches for the position, I just don't know if they visit meta often

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton see chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10964/the-litter-box

Answer (score 2):

[**Everyone else**](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users)

All the candidates offered so far are long time participants with lots of rep.  There are many good candidates who have less rep and less time on the site.  This site is a community project, it belongs to all of us.

Don't let your lack of longevity with the site or lower rep discourage you from offering yourself as a candidate.  Currently we only have one viable candidate for the job, and more is always better.

Anything can happen and if one of the mods gets hit by a bus tomorrow, the SE staff will probably stop here first looking for a replacement.  Posting yourself now increases your chance of getting the job both this time and next time.

If you have an interest but not sure your ready, post yourself anyway and ask for feedback on what it might take to make you ready.  We try to stay a very friendly place, you should expect to get positive feed back and well intended suggestions for improvement.

We have an very extensive support program for new moderators, so this can definitely be a good place to gain skills and experience.

Comment: Agree! Rep shouldn't discourage members to apply! we are all here to make a good pet Q&A resource